# Node.js double console.log output

Tags: node.js, console.log

I'm learning Node.js and I'd like to understand the "why" when code spits out duplicated console.log outputs but only a single response.write outputs.

Heres my simple code example:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    console.log('hello 1');
    response.write('Hello world');
    console.log('hello 2');
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

And on my console/terminal I get:

> hello 1
>
> hello 2
>
> hello 1
>
> hello 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some browsers also send a request to locate the **favicon.ico** file. Since the file isn't present by default, a browser(**Chrome** in particular) will always send two requests: one for the originally requested file and another for favicon.ico. This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402) in Chrome and has been fixed in version 29. **Firefox**, however, requests for favicon.ico only for the first request. If you `console.log` the request URI **path**, you must see a request to `localhost:8000/favicon.ico.`

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    if(request.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        console.log('Favicon was requested');
    }
    console.log('hello 1');
    response.write('Hello world');
    console.log('hello 2');
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Weird. Is there a way to override that? Or is it a matter of "suck it up buttercup"?

Comment: You can `response.end()` to prevent your request handler from being executed on requests to favicon.`if(request.url === '/favicon.ico') { response.end(); }` Not sure if any other way exists.

Comment: @JDillon522 there are chrome extensions to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem myself, and I found out that using something like

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    if(req.url === '/favicon.ico')
    {
        //everything here is ignored
    }
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
res.write("Hello World\n");
res.end();
console.log("Connection made");
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/");
```

is enough to avoid that behaviour. For some reason, when I check req.url and compare it to `'/favicon.ico'` nothing is sent to console, in fact, everything in that block is ignored. I don't know if this behaviour is expected, but you sure could try it.

Comment: Surely all this does is _additionally_ execute the block containing 'everything here is ignored' on a favicon request (and also do everything else)? It won't fix the OP's problem unless you use an _else_ block to contain the remaining logic...

Comment: Well, it's been 6 years, so I'm not sure why I wrote what I wrote or what I was working on then, but yes, I think your comment makes sense. Being a request made for favicon or not shouldn't have an influence on the described behavior, I guess. c.P.u1's answer seems like the best bet on a "fix" here

Answer (score 1):

If you output the header you're telling the server that you found favicon, hence the response is processed and no matter what you get that double `console.log()`. Instead, end it before sending a `writeHead()` or send a 404.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    }
    //code here...

    res.end();
}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it seems to be correct in my version of node (v6.12.0) except that I had to pass a `' '` argument to the end method. This prevents the double console.log output.

Comment: Thank you so much! :). I removed "res.end();" in "if", add var url = require('url'); and modified "req.url" == var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;. It's worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

i think that this problem still persists in chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (32-bit) because when i ran my nodeJS script i saw 2 console.log() statements one was able to print out the query the other was not, so i corrected my code so as to see console.log() statements only once, it was simple all i had to do was add a return statement if the request.url was == (equal to)"/favicon.ico" in the beginning of the code and everything worked fine

previous code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
http.createServer((request,response)=>{
var q = url.parse(request.url,true).query;
console.log(request.url);
console.log('hey there! we got a request from '+q.name+' !');
}).listen(8080);
```

and the output was :

```
/?name=harshit
hey there we got a request from harshit !
/favicon.ico
hey there we got a request from undefined !
```

code after debugging :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
http.createServer((request,response)=>{
if(request.url == "/favicon.ico"){
return ;
}
var q = url.parse(request.url,true).query;
console.log(request.url);
console.log('hey there! we got a request from '+q.name+' !');
}).listen(8080);
```

output :

```
/?name=harshit
hey there we got a request from : harshit !
```

Comment: great answer bro !

Answer (score 0):

in a nutshell the duplication as it is mentioned before is a result of the favicon request so to avoid this problem, I propose you this simple snipet:

```
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
if(pathname != '/favicon.ico')
console.log('hello 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be a Chrome plugin like `JSONView`. I was just trying to figure it out until I tried incognito and realized it was no longer causing the problem. Also was requesting a JSON file.