# How to send parameters to Node.JS basic server

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node.JS and this is the most commonly available example of server by Node.JS

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
//    var name=request.getParameter('name');
//    console.log(name);
    console.log('res: ' + JSON.stringify(response.body));
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World\n");
});
// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);
```

Now when I am executing this from console it works fine, and from browser also it works fine, by hitting the URL: localhost:8000

But now I also want to send some parameters to this server, so I tried localhost:8000/?name=John and few more URL's but none of them work, Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them work?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
var url = require('url');
var name = url.parse(request.url, true).query['name'];
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I have caught the parameter but on the oupput in the console it shows it twice once undefined and and once runs fine here is the code:var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query['name'];
    console.log(query+" prints");

And here is the console output: kapil prints
undefined prints

Comment: @kapilchhattani [That's probably because there are 2 requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952436/node-js-double-console-log-output). If you log the whole `request.url`, you'll probably find that one of them is for a `favicon.ico`. Most browsers will request this immediately after requesting the page.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  Now when I logged the whole URL it says, John prints
/favicon.ico
undefined prints

So I am sure there is some mistake in the code. But not able to figure it out..

Comment: @kapilchhattani Your code may be good. The `function (request, response)` passed to `createServer()` is just called for every request made to the `server` regardless of path, method, or parameters. Like query-string parsing, the routing of URLs and serving of files from disk aren't built-in either. I'd suggest using a library/framework like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) or [Compound](http://compoundjs.com/) to have an easier start.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh ok, so even for the icon it logs the request. Now I get it. Thanks, and yes I have heard about the Express a lot, I will try it out and see what the hooplah is all about..

Answer (score 3):

Node's HTTP API is rather low-level compared to other frameworks/environments that you might be familiar with, so *pleasantries* like a `getParameter()` method don't exist out of the box.

You can get the query-string from the `request`'s [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url), which you can then [`parse`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var query = parsedUrl.query;

    console.log(query.name);

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Appreciate it.