# Node.js print console output two times

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I am trying to create a simple node js server that print 'new client' when any one open the server URL.
This is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function(req, res){
    res.end('hello world');
    console.log('new client');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

but when i open the `http://localhost:8080` the console output 'new client' two times, it should be one line, is this normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js double console.log output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952436/node-js-double-console-log-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal your browser makes more than one call. Every browser make a call to grab /favicon.icon.

Try to console the url and you'll see:

console.log(req.url)

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar experiences with nodejs.

I think it's normal if you are using the chrome browser. Since chrome does some extra requests.

Check here.
[Chrome - multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097711/chrome-multiple-requests)