# Why is my function running twice in command line but not in vscode

Tags: node.js, module, module.exports

I am using a function from one file, in another file, and calling it there. This is causing the function to run twice at the same time when run from the command line, but not when I run it in VSCode.

Here is an example:

```
// fileOne

async function task() {
    console.log('Hello')
}

module.exports = { task }

// fileTwo
const fileOne = require('./fileOne');

fileOne.task();
```

Output when ran in VSCode:

```
Hello
```

Output when ran in Command Line:

```
Hello
Hello
```

I'm not sure why this is happening... No I am not calling it in fileOne by accident because then it would also run twice in VSCode.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you run it from command line ?

Comment: node my_program_here.js

Comment: Can you put contents of the all files? I executed locally on my machine and everything seems to work

Comment: it cant be the contents, or both would run the same way

Comment: @<Salvatore Timpani>can you edit the question to contain all your program's files and explain how you run the program in both cases more clearly? I run the command 'node file2.js' in the terminal and the output is printed to the console only once

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani how did you run it from `vscode` and `command line`. I ran the code using  `node fileOne.js`then it the output was "Hello"  only once

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani can you explain which files are you running and which command you are using to run these?

Comment: node fileTwo in cmd

Comment: I ran in Linux and from command line like Daniel and I only get it printed once, as expected.
Something is missing.

Comment: How are you "running it" in vscode?

Answer (score 1):

If your `fileOne` and `fileTwo` look exactly as in your problem statement, i.e.:

**fileOne.js**:

```
async function task() {
    console.log('Hello')
}

module.exports = { task }
```

**fileTwo.js**:

```
const fileOne = require('./fileOne');

fileOne.task();
```

the output is 1 single 'Hello' when run in the following ways:

1. in **Command Prompt**

   `node fileTwo.js`
2. in **Windows PowerShell**

   `node .\fileTwo.js`
3. in **Linux Bash Terminal**

   `$ nodejs fileTwo.js`

The same applies if you run the script having both files within 1 file (as you mention in the comments).

There were some cases where Node.js would [print the output twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952436/node-js-double-console-log-output), but those were different scenarios.

You can try running just the `fileTwo.js` separately, but as already mentioned, it worked well also under a common file (e.g. your `my_program_here.js` in case it is just a combination of `fileOne.js` and `fileTwo.js`).

Answer (score 0):

```
const fileOne = require('./fileOne');
```

This is based on the './' in different command lines.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a little more? I suspect it is not answering the question.